# Mirror receiver window

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

I assume the Chromecast Chrome extension uses:

```
chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(..)
```

API call to mirror a tab, is there an equivalent API available on the receiver as I assume that Chrome extensions aren't permitted.

I should add the goal is to create a thumbnail of receiver content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such extension on the receiver side. You will not be able to capture any screenshot or things like that either, mainly to preserve the rights of the content owners.

Comment: Thanks Ali - that is a shame.